# Difference between acii code and key codes?

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between ASCII codes and Key codes? I was looking at the code for backslash obtained from `event.which` in javascript. This turned out to be 220. However, when I look at the ASCII table the [ASCII code for backslash](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/backslash-reverse-slash-ascii-code-92.html#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20letter%2C%20character,%22%5C%22%20in%20ASCII%20table.) is 92.

From my research the keyboard event code does not necessarily have to match the ASCII code?

Comment: `event.which` is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which), meaning it could be remove in the future. Instead use `event.key` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original IBM PC [Model M keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_M_keyboard) contained an [Intel 8049 microcontoller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-48) which scanned a wiring matrix of keyboard switches. The scan result was sent as a numeric code to the connected PC using serial communication. The job of interpreting the label of the particular key pressed was left to the operating system. The `which` value of keyboard event objects  is the numeric value received from the keyboard controller chip. Since ASCII doesn't have encodings for arrow and function keys et cetera, `which` was never intended as an ASCII value.

In modern browsers, the keyboard event `key` property usually holds the Unicode string value of a key press determined by converting the key matrix scan result to a Unicode code point based on the keyboard language selected by the PC user, or a description of the key pressed if it not printable.